# Object still moving even when the number of move is 0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, touch

I have an object called `player` and a virtual joystick controller called `joystick` and it contains its knob called `knob` and I've placed the `joystick` and the `knob` in a different movieclip.

I use a script to move the `player` as the amount of movement of the `knob`.

Here's the code :

```
function enterFrame(e:Event): void {
    if (moving) {
        // I move the knob as the touch point moves
        // and the player as the knob moves
    } else {
        // I'm trying to slow down the knob movement to get back to its default position
        // and slow down the player movement until it stopped

        if (knob.x - joystick.x > 0) {
            knob.x -= (knob.x - joystick.x)*.5;
            player.x -= -(knob.x - joystick.x)*.9;
        }
        if (knob.x - joystick.x < 0) {
            knob.x += -((knob.x - joystick.x)*.5);
            player.x += (knob.x - joystick.x)*.9;
        }
        if (knob.y - joystick.y > 0) {
            knob.y -= (knob.y - joystick.y)*.5;
            player.y -= -((knob.y - joystick.y)*.9);
        }
        if (knob.y - joystick.y < 0) {
            knob.y += -((knob.y - joystick.y)*.5);
            player.y += (knob.y - joystick.y)*.9;
        }

        // Then I use trace to trace the player x position
        trace(player.x);
    }
}
```

And what I got is when I move the knob to left position and `touch_end` it, the slow down works but the `player` keep moving left by .01. But when I move the knob to another directions and `touch_end` it, the slow down works well until the `player` stopped.

Why could that happens?

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: trace("moving: " + moving) inside your enterFrame function please and let me know what happens. When the player is moving .01, is moving true or false?

Comment: It's `false`, I don't even know why

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a floating-point precision effect.  If you start with `knob.x` at 1 and `joystick.x` at 0.5, you'll get:

```
knob.x      joystick.x  knob-joystick   knob-joystick/2 
1           0.5         0.5             0.25
0.75        0.5         0.25            0.125
0.625       0.5         0.125           0.0625
0.5625      0.5         0.0625          0.03125
0.53125     0.5         0.03125         0.015625
0.515625    0.5         0.015625        0.0078125
```

It's clearly trending towards zero, but there's a small remaining positive value when you calculate `knob.x-joystick.x`.

Note: Since your `if` statement that changes `knob.x` is in an `EnterFrame` listener, any joystick changes in response to user input will take longer than this to occur.

Instead of checking that your difference is > 0, check that it's greater than some small guard value, e.g.

```
if (knob.x - joystick.x > 0.01) {
    knob.x -= (knob.x - joystick.x)*.5;
    player.x -= -(knob.x - joystick.x)*.9;
}
//etc.
```

You might also add some guard code at the end of your listener:

```
if (knob.x > 0 && knob.x < 0.01) {
    knob.x = 0;
}
//etc.
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. +1

Comment: @G.Chiko Did you add the guard code to all four `if` blocks?  Also, double-check that no other code is updating the `player` position.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I did. And there's no other code is controlling the `player` position.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after working around it, finally I did it!

I use `Math.floor` "trick" to force the `-0.0249999999999828` (the last position when moving to left which make the `player` keep moving left even when I'm not control it anymore) to be change to `0`.

Here's the code :

```
function enterFrame(e:Event): void {
    .... // bla bla bla
    } else {
        if (knob.x > joystick.x) {
            knob.x -= (knob.x - joystick.x)*.5;
            player.x -= -((knob.x - joystick.x)*.9);
        }
        if (knob.x < joystick.x) {
            knob.x += -(Math.floor((knob.x - joystick.x)*.5));
            player.x += Math.floor((knob.x - joystick.x)*.9);
        }
        if (knob.y > joystick.y) {
            knob.y -= (knob.y - joystick.y)*.5;
            player.y -= -((knob.y - joystick.y)*.9);
        }
        if (knob.y < joystick.y) {
            knob.y += -(Math.floor((knob.y - joystick.y)*.5));
            player.y += Math.floor((knob.y - joystick.y)*.9);
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the `if (knob.x - joystick.x > 0)` (and all of kind of this) to `if (knob.x > joystick.x)` I think it's more efficient to detect where the knob is (right, left, up, down).

Or maybe you guys can find another way more efficient and more exact? It would help me

Comment: The only "problem" with this is it lends itself to jerky motion. It essentially tunes your Number value into an Int value. If it works for you that's great. But I favor the answer posted by Brian. It doesn't force a call to a Math method which can be more expensive and it only kicks in when the move value gets very low. Yours is kicking in when move is 3.2 it forces move to 3. When it goes to 2.9 it forces it to 2. Better to only force it to 0 when it is less than 0.3 or something like that.

Comment: I've tried Brian's code, but the `player` keep moving. What should I do? Or maybe there's something I missed?

Comment: Do you know how to debug? Ctrl shift enter. Put some break points in the code. Then step through the code during the slow down. You will be able to see all the variables values and where the play head is going to very useful.